# Delete all substrings from given string that begin with certain chars

Tags: php

I have a giant string and I want to delete all substrings within that string that start with a particular set of characters, in this case (' http) and end with a space. Framed differently, I want to delete all words (urls) that begin with (' http) - note the space as I have urls that begin with a parenthesis that I don't want to delete e.g., '(http..)' So far what I have looks like this but I'm not sure if regex is a better option here?

```
while (strpos($body, ' http') !== false) {
      $beginningPos = strpos($body, ' http');
      $endPos = // somehow find the location of the first occurrence of a space after $beginningPos 
      // delete substring between $beginningPos and endPos
}
```

Comment: I'd go with regex. Can you provide a sample of your string? Would a URL ever have a space in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with preg_replace.  The following does exactly what you described:

```
preg_replace('/ (http[^ ]*) /', ' ', $string);
```

This version will also remove the urls if they occur at the very beginning and/or very end of the string:

```
preg_replace('/(^| )(http[^ ]*)( |$)/', ' ', $string);
```

Or you may want to use any/all whitespace as delimiters, rather than just a space character, like so:

```
preg_replace('/(^|\s+)(http\S*)(\s+|$)/', ' ', $string);
```